# Фреймворки - это круто?

Tags: php, mysql

Не хочу создавать холивар. Просто очень интересно нужно ли ими пользоваться или нет. Фреймворк признак профессионализма? Или же это всёравно что вместо самописки установить CMS с тысячей плагинов и кучей ненужных функций? Пожалуйста расскажите :) А то думаю, что изучать сейчас: какой-нибудь фреймворк, или лучше переходить уже к другому языку)

**UPD:**
Всем спасибо. Буду выбирать фреймворк) Кто поставил минус - редиска, даже не обосновал :)

Comment: если вы для простого сайта пишете CMS то вы не професионал.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Признак профессионализма - адекватный выбор способа решения задачи. Если вы для написания сайта-визитки используете тяжеловесный фреймворк, то вы не профессионал, а любитель стрелять из пушки по воробьям. А может, вы просто не знаете, как писать без фреймворков (в большей степени это относится к людям, которые изучение JavaScript начинают с jQuery, и этим ограничиваются). Если вы пишете тяжёлый проект полностью самостоятельно, то вы не профессионал, ибо заново изобретаете велосипед и срываете все сроки. Фреймворки знать надо, но использовать их повсеместно - нет.

Comment: Почему из пушки по воробьям? Современные компьютеры и не такое переживут. А если человек отлично знает фреймворк, а при написании без фреймворков элементарные вещи забудет сделать? Пусть все пишет привычным инструментом....

Answer (score 1):

я думаю все зависит от задачи.
если у вас куча времени. Пишите сайт или что-то ещё с нуля.
Придумывайте свои реализации.

Фреймворки же, это такой инструмент, который упрощает многие моменты в написании кода сайта и т.п.

CMS и фреймворки это не одно и тоже, хотя оба они инструменты.

Если хорошо работать с инструментом, то такого человека можно назвать профессионалом работы с этим инстурментом.